# Liferay logging level

Tags: logging, log4j, liferay, liferay-6

Is there a way to set Liferay's **global** logging level? I am aware of it's console in the Server Administration but I want to set a global level not to a package level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by unpacking portal-impl.jar found in $server/applications/liferay-portal/WEB-INF/lib and replacing the contents of META-INF/portal-log4j.xml with my requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the way log4j can be configured, any global setting can be overridden by a package level setting.

You can remove any configuration individual packages (if you have any). Then the setting for the `rootLogger` will take effect.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

**Update**

To override Liferay's default logging settings, you can create a [portal-log4j-ext.xml](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Configuring+Logs#section-Configuring+Logs-Creating+a+custom+configuration+file%3a+portal-log4j-ext.xml). Just define a logger for the package `com.liferay` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I agree, do you know a way to remove the declarations of each package in liferay? I can't configure each of the 237 different packages. Thanks

Comment: I am using glassfish and can't find where to put the file for it to work. Tried also this link but it's not resolved: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14793695

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work in Glassfish. I'm afraid you maybe out of luck. If you use Enterprise version of Liferay, I suggest you raise a ticket.

Comment: When I change portal-log4j-ext.xml does it need a liferat restart? If so; is there a workaround to that requirement? I can't get my logs to show.